# Is there a way for fixing this error in IntelliJ Idea, plugin is Appium Studio?

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, error-handling, appium

I am trying to access Appium Studio on IntelliJ Idea and I have been getting this Plugin Error on startup. I enable Appium Studio and the try to restart IntelliJ but when it opens I get this error message:

[image: PLUGIN ERROR]

```
Plugin 'com.intellij.STAintellij.intellij_plugin' failed to initialize and will be disabled. Please restart IntelliJ IDEA.

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.experitest.STAintellij.controller.STAIntelliJProjectController
             PluginClassLoader(plugin=PluginDescriptor(name=Appium Studio, id=com.intellij.STAintellij.intellij_plugin, descriptorPath=plugin.xml, path=~\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IdeaIC2021.2\plugins\experiJ-21.7.220, version=21.7.220, package=null), packagePrefix=null, instanceId=28, state=active)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:254)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.registerComponent(ComponentMana....
```

And then it is disabled. What may the cause be for this error?

Comment: Please contact plugin vendor directly: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13850-appium-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be fixed on next version of STA Plugin (v.21.10)
You can also downgrade to v.21.6

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).